# How to collect data which exists centre or border of the cluster?

Tags: python, data-mining, clustering

After applying clustering algorithm I need to extract those data which exists centre of the cluster and which exists border of the cluster. How could I do this by using python.

I use k-means clustering algorithm and divide those data into 19 cluster. I am also using scikit learn library.

**Edited:**

Here's my plot after clustering: 
[image]

Comment: Can you share a plot of your data?We might need to manually trim the data(not quite sure) as we will have different centroids coordinates..

Comment: As I am new in clustering and I have 682 instances with 35 features that's why I don't know how I can plot? 
If I provides centroids willbe it helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` documentation can be fouind here :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

You can define a function to extract your data ID somthing like this

```
def ClusterIndicesNumpy(clustNum, labels_array): 
    return np.where(labels == cluster)[0]
```

To get samples from cluster 3 for example:

```
ClusterIndicesNumpy(3, km.labels_)
```

Comment: I need those data in every(19) cluster that are very close to the centre.
By using numpy.where how could I identify those data ?